# Byte to Integer why Number changes

Tags: java, casting, byte, short

Why the number changes from byte to integer or from short to byte to integer?

Here the code:

```
public class TypeCasting {
    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        
        short c = 292;
        int d = (byte) c;
        
        System.out.println(d); // 36

    }
}
```

Comment: Does 292 fit in a byte?

Comment: I was thinking of answering along the lines of 'it wraps around to negative' until I saw the above comment and realized it's beyond negative wrapping and wraps around completely.

Answer (score 1):

```
292 = 0001 0010 0100
36  = 0000 0010 0100
```

Change 292 from Short to a Byte removes the left-hand bits (the first 4). When you re-cast it to an Int those bits are now lost so you will still only remain with 36.